# Invert PDF colours?

Tags: pdf, printing, colors

I'm trying to print a PDF given to us at the University. The PDF writer has (unhelpfully) used a black background with white text, see an example image.

[image: Black background PDF]

I've tried the Edit > Preference > Accessibility options in Adobe Reader to try and invert the colour of the background but without success. I was able to modify the text, but not the background. Even so, this changed *all* the text, not only white text, so its' not quite what I wanted anyway.

My printer options also didn't allow any inversions. I could screen-scrape each page and manually invert, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant / automated way to swap the background and text colours.

The related question [invert colours](https://superuser.com/questions/449724/is-it-possible-to-invert-text-and-background-colors-in-a-pdf-when-printing) was asked over 3 years ago and no answer worked nor was accepted. Hopefully there is a solution now.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/449724/is-it-possible-to-invert-text-and-background-colors-in-a-pdf-when-printing

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that question but none of the answers worked over 3 years ago (and none of them work for me now). More importantly, the OP accepted none of the answers.

Comment: Accessability options do nothing to "images" so changing the background does nothing, changing the text just dissapears it into the image. There lies the problem. Weirdstuff:  windows magnifyer will invert the colors, and a "print screen" will still grab it that way, not real useful for ease of printing.  I assume that any viewer (or copy paste) conversion that could drop images, would not solution it because there will also be images used in the  presentation.

Comment: You might be right about the background being an image. I tried a solution offered in another question about contrast in PDFs called eVince Document Viewer. That allows the PDF to be viewed in inverted colours, but printing still uses the original colours. Still haven't found a solution...

Comment: If it was simply text on a colored background, you could suppress printing of the background.  However, Psycogeek is probably right about the page being an image.  You can test that by trying to select a portion of text.  If it's an image, it would be labor-intensive.  You could do something like import each page into Photoshop or GIMP, then select and modify each color in layers and save revised pages.  Is your time worth more than the wasted ink?

Comment: @fixer1234: :o) good point. No, the wasted ink is a probably only a small fraction of the cost of doing this manually page by page. Surprising that there isn't a simple solution, though. Even if Adobe Reader doesn't offer the functionality I need, this seems like the sort of thing that the printer itself would offer a feature for.