# How do I invert the colors of my pdf on mac?

Tags: macos, pdf, colors, preview

I'm currently a high school student and our professor insists on using his online notes for class- but the only problem in this situation is that the notes he has provided are in an inconvenient black-background colour scheme which is difficult and expensive to print. Is there any way to invert the colours of the pdf like one does on images? Bonus points if it is mac compatible.

Comment: Does [printing - How can you invert the colors of a PDF? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/310960/how-can-you-invert-the-colors-of-a-pdf?rq=1) answer you question?

Comment: (1) Try the website [Invert PDF Colors](https://www.i2pdf.com/invert-pdf-colors). (2) Do you have Adobe Pro available? ([link](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/how-do-i-invert-colors-on-document/td-p/12763816)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this natively, with one wisely-chosen key command - **but** you lose the vector fonts, you get raster png & you get one file per page.

Set up an Automator action - I used a Quick Action [Service] which can be triggered by key command.

Workflow receives - PDF in Finder
Render PDF Pages as Images
Copy Finder items - I chose a dedicated folder for this because the end result can be a lot of files.
Apply Quartz Composition Filter to Image Files - Colour Invert

[image]

You might wonder why I didn't use the obvious Apply Quartz Filter to PDF… - because it doesn't have an invert option :\

Save this, then in System prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services add a key command. [Watch out for key commands using Q… or you'll accidentally log yourself off or lock the screen ;)

[image]

Done.
Select a PDF in Finder, hit your key command, a few seconds later you have a folder full of individual colour-inverted png files.

<sup>Before & after [intentionally small image]</sup>

[image]

All of this is available in Ventura too - it's just harder to find [one reason I won't use it;)

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat (Reader) you have the Accessibility settings where you can change the display of text.

Comment: That's unlikely to change the print colours.