# pdf reader for Windows which has night mode?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

Looking for a pdf reader for Windows which has a night mode which is reading white text on black background. The closest I found is Adobe Reader with accessibility mode and high contrast but it has some text (like hyperlinks) in blue which was hard to read.

Any recommendations?

Comment: [This thread](http://superuser.com/questions/286403/software-to-read-pdfs-with-inverted-colors-windows) may be relevant, but it may be outdated. Not marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Adobe Reader works fine now. I had to uncheck the 'Only change the color text or line art" option.

Comment: This solved my issue. It works. Answers to the other 'dup' question do no mention Adobe Reader. Whoever deleted my answer made a mistake and it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

[evince](https://projects.gnome.org/evince/) has a night mode option at `view - inverted colors`.

Should result in black background, white text and as noted in the comments, yellow hyperlinks.

Comment: Hyperlinks in Evince with inverted colors are displayed in bright yellow.